# Non-negative integer solutions to equation $(1+x+y)^2+y-x=(1+w+z)^2+z-w$

Tags: number-theory

As the title mentions, I am trying to "solve" the equation

$$(1+x+y)^2+y-x=(1+w+z)^2+z-w$$

for w,x,y,z non-negative integers. In particular, I want to prove that the only solutions are $w=x, y=z$

Unfortunately, I have made 0 progress on this problem. I could not even solve the case where $x=0$ i.e.

$$(1+y)^2+y = (1+w+z)^2+z-w$$ with all variables $\in \mathbb{Z}$ Does it mean $w=0$ and $y=w$

Please help me with this weird problem

Thank you, Gareth

Comment: I wonder if this is related to https://projecteuler.net/problem=674

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We rearrange to obtain the equation $(1+x+y)^2 - (1+w+z)^2 = x+z-y-w$, and factorising the LHS gives $(2+x+y+z+w)(x+y-w-z) = y+z-x-w$.

Note that $|2+x+y+z+w| > |y+z-x-w|$, so there are no solutions unless the other bracket is $0$, i.e. $x+y-w-z = 0$ and $x+z-y-w=0$. This forces $x+y=w+z$ and $x+z=y+w$, and subtracting the two equations gives $y-z = z-y \implies y=z$. An identical argument gives $w=x$, and so we are done.

Comment: Thank you! That is a great answer. I tried factoring LHS but didn't realise that would work